# How can I make a Perl package for scalars?

Tags: perl

I already use a Perl package (Funx.pm) for reusable code.  But I'd like it to include a bunch of scalars as return values, i.e.

```
my $SUCCESS         =   0;
my $NOFILE      =   1;
my $COPYFAIL        =   2;
my $APPRUNNING      =   3;
...and on and on....
```

Is there a way to do so and be able to just use the variables without have to import each one nor having to use Funx:: when using them?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Can't export lexical variables. Starting by making them constants (see constant.pm). 2) Exporter allows you to specify default exports. Alternatively, it allows you to create tags the represent a group of exports. 3) Those names could easily conflict with other symbols if imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefacing this by saying that it is a bad idea, imagine if someone sets a different value to `$SUCCESS` anywhere in the code base. Using `$Funx::SUCCESS` is a much better way to go, it also provides context as to what is the success of.

`our()` makes a variable visible across all scopes, including across packages.

```
package Funx;
our($SUCCESS, $NOFILE, $COPYFAIL, $APPRUNNING);
$SUCCESS         =   0;
$NOFILE      =   1;
$COPYFAIL        =   2;
$APPRUNNING      =   3;

package main;
say($SUCCESS, $Funx::SUCCESS); # both work
```

Comment: Thanks.  For now I can live with the risk of reassignment because I'm the only one using my code.

Comment: Maybe I should switch my long list of return values to constants?

Comment: Your `say($SUCCESS)` in the `main` package only works because `our` has a lexical effect and `package` doesn't create a new lexical scope. If (as would be more normal) `package Funx` and `package main` were in different files, then his code wouldn't work. You should probably add something about using [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) to work round that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a module that exports constants.

```
package RPi::Const;

use strict;
use warnings;

our $VERSION = '1.04';

require Exporter;
use base qw( Exporter );
our @EXPORT_OK = ();
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( all => \@EXPORT_OK );

use constant {
    RPI_MODE_WPI => 0,
    RPI_MODE_GPIO => 1,
    RPI_MODE_GPIO_SYS => 2,
    RPI_MODE_PHYS => 3,
    RPI_MODE_UNINIT => -1,
};

{ # mode

    my @const = qw(
        RPI_MODE_WPI
        RPI_MODE_GPIO
        RPI_MODE_GPIO_SYS
        RPI_MODE_PHYS
        RPI_MODE_UNINIT
    );

    push @EXPORT_OK, @const;
    $EXPORT_TAGS{mode} = \@const;
}

use constant {
    MCP23017_IODIRA     => 0x00,
    MCP23017_IODIRB     => 0x01,
    MCP23017_IPOLA      => 0x02,
    MCP23017_IPOLB      => 0x03,
    MCP23017_GPINTENA   => 0x04,
    MCP23017_GPINTENB   => 0x05,
    MCP23017_DEFVALA    => 0x06,
    MCP23017_DEFVALB    => 0x07,
    MCP23017_INTCONA    => 0x08,
    MCP23017_INTCONB    => 0x09,
    MCP23017_IOCONA     => 0x0A,
    MCP23017_IOCONB     => 0x0B,
    MCP23017_GPPUA      => 0x0C,
    MCP23017_GPPUB      => 0x0D,
    MCP23017_INTFA      => 0x0E,
    MCP23017_INTFB      => 0x0F,
    MCP23017_INTCAPA    => 0x10,
    MCP23017_INTCAPB    => 0x11,
    MCP23017_GPIOA      => 0x12,
    MCP23017_GPIOB      => 0x13,
    MCP23017_OLATA      => 0x14,
    MCP23017_OLATB      => 0x15,

    MCP23017_INPUT      => 1,
    MCP23017_OUTPUT     => 0,
};

{ # MCP23017 GPIO Expander Registers

    my @const = qw(
        MCP23017_IODIRA
        MCP23017_IODIRB
        MCP23017_IPOLA
        MCP23017_IPOLB
        MCP23017_GPINTENA
        MCP23017_GPINTENB
        MCP23017_DEFVALA
        MCP23017_DEFVALB
        MCP23017_INTCONA
        MCP23017_INTCONB
        MCP23017_IOCONA
        MCP23017_IOCONB
        MCP23017_GPPUA
        MCP23017_GPPUB
        MCP23017_INTFA
        MCP23017_INTFB
        MCP23017_INTCAPA
        MCP23017_INTCAPB
        MCP23017_GPIOA
        MCP23017_GPIOB
        MCP23017_OLATA
        MCP23017_OLATB
        MCP23017_INPUT
        MCP23017_OUTPUT
    );

    push @EXPORT_OK, @const;
    $EXPORT_TAGS{mcp23017_registers} = \@const;
}

1;
__END__
```

In your calling scripts, you can import each bundle (tag), or by using the `:all` tag, you can import all the separate groups:

```
use RPi::Const qw(:mcp23017_registers); # single grouping
```

...or

```
use RPi::Const qw(:all); # all groupings
```

Then you can use any of the imported constants:

```
sub mode {
    my ($self, $pin, $mode) = @_;

    if (! defined $mode){
        my $reg = $pin > 7 ? MCP23017_IODIRB : MCP23017_IODIRA;
        my $bit = _pinBit($pin);
        return getRegisterBit($self->_fd, $reg, $bit);
    }

    _check_mode($mode);

    pinMode($self->_fd, $pin, $mode);
}
```